# Insert variable name as object value JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I need same result like below but inserting the item 'key' into object B with javascript not manually

```
//example-----------------------:
var A = 0;
var B = {key:A};

console.log(B.key); // return 0
A = 1;
console.log(B.key); // return 1
//---------------------------------------------

//I need same result like above but inserting the item into object B with javascript not manually
var A = 0;
var B = {};

B['key'] = A; //Not work because this insert the value of A i need to insert character A as variable not string not 0
```

Thank you

EDITED:
Ok ... sorry for the mistake. Is true in mi example both returns 0. I have solved mi problem with this: B['key'] = function(){return A} Thank's for your aclarations

Comment: Your first example return 0 for both on Chrome and Firefox at least.

Comment: It returns 0 in any browser as the variables are used by value, not by reference.

Comment: You can't do that in JavaScript.

Comment: The nearest you can do is this: var a = { value: 0 }; var b = { key: a }; console.log(b.key.value); a.value=1; console.log(b.key.value);

Comment: @Gusman I was septic because he provided a test case, so even if I knew it wouldn't work, I tried it before calling him out.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have assign/pass/call by reference.

Comment: @EmileBergeron yes yes, it was just a point that it happens in any js engine, js passes primitives by value, not by reference and that's why it happens. only way to achieve something similar is to use an object as objects are passed by reference.

Comment: @Gusman: Objects are not *passed* by reference. There are represented *as* references. That's a difference. Everything is pass-by-value in JS.

Comment: @FelixKling hmmm, can you clarify it? if you pass an object to a function and modify that object it will modify the object, so the object has been passed by reference, no?

Comment: @Gusman: No, *pass-by-reference* means this: `function foo(a) { a = 42; }; var b = 21; foo(b); console.log(b); // 42`. It describes the relationship between bindings, not values. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference . Of course what you say about objects is correct, but that is not called *pass-by-reference* (a common confusion). If you look at the Wikipedia page, this technique could be called *pass-by-sharing*, but it's not a very common term.

Comment: @FelixKling ok, i understand what you mean but I'm not sure if it's correct (not trying to be pedantic, just trying to understand it). My main language is C# and you can read anywhere in the docs that objects are passed by reference, and that doesn't means that replacing the object inside a function will replace the external object, that would be a reference to a reference object (in c++ terms, a pointer to a pointer object). Isn't that exactly the same that JS does?

Comment: @Gusman: Then the docs are wrong or simply imprecise. Pass-by-reference means that the function receives a reference to a *variable*, not a value. I think the Wikipedia article clarifies that quite well (and describes techniques to simulate pass-by-reference).

Comment: @FelixKling hmm, objects are stored as references to the object, so passing that reference indeed passes the object as a reference, as a reference to the object, not as a reference to the variable holding the object... so the object has been passed by reference. Anyway, I understand what you said but that's only appliable to a variable, and I was stating that *the object* was passed by reference, not the variable holding the reference to the object.

Comment: @MTK No problem, welcome to the Stack Overflow (and so you know, I'm not one of the downvoter)

Comment: *to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's in general not possible in JavaScript, there are no such things as references or pointers.

Given that you are using a property here, you can emulate it though with [getters and setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters):

```
var A = 0;
var B = {get key() { return A; }, set key(v) { A = v; }};

console.log(B.key); // 0
A = 1;
console.log(B.key); // 1
```

Comment: I'm so used to avoiding these as they're incompatible in <IE8 that I didn't check back and now they are supported on all major browsers (>=IE9) http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#test-Object/array_literal_extensions_Getter_accessors

Answer (score 0):

Since everything is passed by value in JS (as noted by [Gusman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558062/insert-variable-name-as-object-value-javascript?noredirect=1#comment62604652_37558062) and [FelixKling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558062/insert-variable-name-as-object-value-javascript?noredirect=1#comment62604771_37558062) in the comments), what could work is this

```
var A = { key: 0 };
var B = A;

console.log(B.key); // 0
A.key = 1; // notice the difference here
console.log(B.key); // 1
```

Instead of trying to keep the reference to a variable inside another object, which is not possible as variable are passed by value, keep the value inside an object and pass the object around.

Since the question is about dynamically constructing B, you could do:

```
var A = { value: 0 };
var B = {};

// your logic somewhere
function applyToB (newKey) {
    B[newKey] = A;
}
applyToB('key');

// the expected result
console.log(B.key.value); // 0
A.value = 1;
console.log(B.key.value); // 1
```

Comment: Please provide a comment if you're going to downvote